# C# Cannot implicitly convert type System.DBNull to string

Tags: c#, excel

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DBNull' to 'string'

I am trying to pull data from a worksheet and I get the above error. It happens on the `string Text` line. What can I do convert this or ignore the null?

```
var excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Workbook workbook =  excel.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Documents\ANIs.xlsx");
Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[1];

    Range a1 = worksheet.get_Range("A1","B2");

    object rawValue = a1.Value;
    string Text = a1.Text; //<--Error Occurs here. 

    for (int i = 0; i < a1.Count; i++)
    {
        if (a1.Text != null)
            Console.WriteLine("{1}", rawValue, Text);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: You have to check the value before conversion: `if (a is DbNull) ...`

Comment: Should I put that before the error line or change the error line? Sorry I am not understanding where that fits in.

Comment: Your code would appear just to output a1.Text 4 times - inside the loop you need something like a1.Cells[I].Text. Also note that Cells is not an array but a property that uses 1 as a starting offset NOT 0.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need a Conditional Statement.  If you call `ToString()` on certain types, if it is `Null` it will throw an exception.  The easiest remedy would be:

```
if(!(a1 is DBNull))
{
     // Do Something
}
```

Hopefully this clarifies a bit.

```
// Sample:
var range = worksheet.get_Range("A1","B2");
if(!(range is DBNull))
{
     object raw = range.Value;
     string text = range.Text;

     // Loop here
}
```

Also, you need to not use `Text` as capital, that is predefined and can't be used as a variable.  Another error in the code.  Note in comments, what @RonBeyer said about the `Text` being used.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What is it saying?

Comment: if (! (a1 is DBNull)) throws an error "the given expression is never of the provided 'system.DBnull' type.

Comment: Actually you can use `Text` as a variable, it just then requires you to prefix the form property (assuming the code is inside a form or control) with `this.Text`. Its not an error, just not advisable.

Comment: @RonBeyer I didn't realize that, I always heard never do it.  So I assumed it was error related.